# Problem with Java FileReader

Tags: java, text-files, filereader

Hello I have this in my code

```
File file = new File("words.txt");
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    String theWord;    
    while (scanFile.hasNext()){
        theWord = scanFile.next();
        words.add(theWord);
    }
```

But for some reason I am getting a

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

I have the words.txt file in the same folder as all of my .java files

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How do you execute the program? From the command-line or from an IDE. Most IDEs have an option to specify the working directory of an application. You would have to put your file there.

Comment: Is the file already opened elsewhere (including elsewhere in your code without being closed)?  The Javadoc for `java.io.FileReader.FileReader( java.io.File )` states that a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown "if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading."  If you're sure the file exists and that it's a regular file, then there must be some reason it can't be opened.  Make sure the file's permissions allow for reading as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tip: add this line to your code...

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then compare that path with where your file actually is. The problem should be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 5):

The file should reside in the directory from which you *execute* the application, i.e. the *working directory*.

Answer (score 4):

Generally it's a good idea to package data files with your code, but then using `java.io.File` to read them is a problem, as it's hard to find them. The solution is to use the `getResource()` methods in `java.lang.ClassLoader` to open a stream to a file. That way the `ClassLoader` looks for your files in the location where your code is stored, wherever that may be.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource( "words.txt" );
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Comment: Or simply `InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "words.txt" );`

Comment: thank you guys. this helped

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified an absolute path. The path would therefore be treated as a path, relative to the current working directory of the process. Usually this is the directory from where you've launched the Main-Class.

If you're unsure about the location of the working directory, you can print it out using the following snippet:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Fixing the problem will require adding the necessary directories in the original path, to locate the file.