# Reading a file using FileReader and Scanner

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am a Java beginner and have read similar questions but still I dont get why my code is showing a FileNotFound Exception.
My file is in the same directory.

My code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = in.nextInt();
        double y = in.nextDouble();
        float g = in.nextFloat();
        String a = in.next();
        File file = new File("v.txt");
        System.out.println(x + "" + y + "" + g + "" + a); 
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        String u = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
17: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                                  ^
1 error
```

Comment: Same directory from where you are running the code?

Comment: Are you running your code from an IDE, and if so, what IDE?

Comment: @AniketThakur Yes. Both my .java file and .txt file are in the same folder.

Comment: Also you might want tp use `exists()` on file object before you perform read/write operations on it.

Comment: @Alex I am running on Ubuntu through terminal.

Comment: "My file is in the same directory." where exactly is your file located and how are you running it? `new File("foo.bar")` will represent location `./foo.bar` where `.` represents current location of your console.

Comment: @edbale try `-cp .` while running your java code.

Comment: Try moving the printing out of `getAbsolutePath` up, before you create the `Scanner`. That will tell you where it is actually looking for the file.

Comment: `have read similar questions` Sorry, but I don't believe that. Have you tried to search for your error message `must be caught or declared to be thrown`?

Comment: @Tom I searched FileReader and scanner questions. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266188/problem-with-java-filereader which seems to be exactly the same question......

Comment: @edbale Once you can run your program, try it with a file that's *really* missing and see what happens - how a *run time error* looks like if it isn't caught by the program. What you have seen and reported as an "exception" is a compiler error message - make sure to distinguish these from anything else.

Comment: @Tom why downote, I would be banned from furter questions.

Comment: @edbale You've searched for something different. A `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown if the file couldn't be found during runtime. Your Error is triggered by the compiler, because your code is wrong (unhandled exception). This is something different and that is why I've asked you if you've searched for the error message.

Comment: @Tom It's pretty obvious ed was in a blind alley. Please reconsider.

Comment: @laune Let us hope that he now know that the message is very important, as well :D. And you're right, I've reconsidered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are encountering a compile time error:

```
error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
```

This is a simple way of fixing it:

```
public class reader {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
         //...
   }
}
```

although using try {...} catch(...){ } is a better way of dealing with the possible run time exception.

Comment: Yes it worked, but If I know that my file exists why do I need to put this ? Is it required whenever I access a file ?

Comment: ["try-with-resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) would also be possible.

Comment: @edbale You know, but the compiler doesn't know that you know - and he wouldn't trust you or anybody else reading or writing this sentence ;-)

Comment: @edbale "*but If I know that my file exists why do I need to put this?*" are you sure that your file will always be there? Is it physically impossible to delete it?

Comment: Btw you should use scanner to "parse" files and FileReader  + BufferedReader to read files